# how to insert values in a table with foreign key field

Tags: mysql

I am creating a database where I have a table with a foreign key. I am using the following command:

```
insert into ques_bank 
    (q_no, uid, question) 
values 
    (NULL, select uid from user_info where username ='more','jdkjfsd dkskdsn skdjsd');
```

But it gives a syntax error. 
I am having troubles with foreign key. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no information on the definition of your table (what foreign key?) but based on your SQL you should use a `select` to enter it:

```
insert into ques_bank 
    (q_no, uid, question) 
select null, uid, 'jdkjfsd dkskdsn skdjsd' from user_info where username ='more';
```

or:

```
insert into ques_bank 
    (uid, question) 
select uid, 'jdkjfsd dkskdsn skdjsd' from user_info where username ='more';
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error comes from the `SELECT` needing its own parentheses:

```
(NULL,
 ( select uid from user_info where username ='more' ),
'jdkjfsd dkskdsn skdjsd')
```

But @Marco provides a 'better' way to write the query.

`FOREIGN KEYs` are irrelevant?